# How can I solve this kind of systems: $\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rcl} 3x-y'-2y&=& 8t\\ x'-2x+y &=&16e^{-t} \end{array}\right.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this kind of systems: $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rcl} 3x-y'-2y&=& 8t\\ x'-2x+y &=&16e^{-t} \end{array}\right.$$

I don't know how to approach it. **I tried:**  $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rcl} y'&=& -8t+3x-2y\\ x' &=&16e^{-t}+2x-y \end{array}\right.$$ But since $y,y' x$ are mixed seems difficult, to continue.

Comment: @Moo could you show how to convert into matrix?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Are you given the initial conditions for this system?

Comment: @Semiclassical no, they only ask for the general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

From the first equation, you have
$$x=\frac 13(y'+2y+8t)\tag 1$$ Replace in the second to have
$$y''-y=16 t+48 e^{-t}-8\tag 2$$ which not difficult.

When solved for $y$, go back to $(1)$ to obtain $x$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [*Linear Nonhomogeneous Systems of Differential Equations with Constant Coefficients*](https://www.math24.net/linear-nonhomogeneous-systems-differential-equations-constant-coefficients/).

You have

$$X'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}= AX+f(t) = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\3&-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}16e^{-t}\\-8t\end{pmatrix}$$

Next, follow [*Variation of Paramters*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx) or many different methods to solve such a system.

Can you proceed?

You should get

$$x(t)= \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-t} \left(-16 \left(e^t+1\right) t+c_1 \left(3 e^{2 t}-1\right)-c_2 e^{2 t}-24+c_2\right)\\y(t)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-32 t-3 e^{-t} (16 t+8+c_1-c_2)+(3 c_1-c_2) e^t+16\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's to suppose that $y'=y'(t)$ and $x'=x'(t)$ with $t\in I$ and $I$ an open interval, then
note that $$\begin{cases} 3x-y'-2y&=& 8t\\ x'-2x+y &=&16e^{-t} \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}-y'&=&-3x+2y+8t\\ x'&=&2x-y+16e^{-t} \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}y'&=&3x-2y-8t\\ x'&=& 2x-y+16e^{-t} \end{cases}$$

Finally, note that the system of ordinary differential equations can be written as

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} x'(t) \\ y'(t) \end{pmatrix}}_{X'(t)}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 &-2 \end{pmatrix} }_{A(t)}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}}_{X(t)}+\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 16e^{-t} \\ -8t \end{pmatrix}}_{F(t)} $$

Since you have a linear nonhomogeneous systems of differential equations with constant coefficients, so you can first to find the solution for $F(t)\equiv 0$ and then you can find the solution with $F(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 16e^{-t} \\ -8t \end{pmatrix}$.

1. **First Part:** Let's to find the complementary solution, since that $$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 &-2 \end{pmatrix}$$
   It's easy to see that the eigenvalues are given by $$\boxed{\lambda_{1}=-1} \quad \text{and} \quad \boxed{\lambda_{2}=1}$$
   and yours corresponding eigenvectors are given by $$\boxed{v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}} \quad \text{and} \quad \boxed{v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}} $$
   so, since that $\lambda_{1}\not=\lambda_{2}$ and $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ then we can conclude that $$\color{blue}{\boxed{X_{c}(t)=c_{1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} e^{-t}+c_{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{t}}}$$

> Remember that if $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{n}$ be reals eigenvalues and differents of the coefficients matrix $A(t)$ of system $X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$ and if $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}$ be correspondent eigenvectors. Therefore, the general solution of $X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$ on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ is given by $$\color{blue}{\boxed{X(t)=c_{1}v_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}t}+c_{2}v_{2}e^{\lambda_{2}t}+\cdots+c_{n}v_{n}e^{\lambda_{n}t}}}$$ with $c_{1},c_{2},\ldots,c_{n}$ constants.

2. **Second Part:** In general this is the tricky part, you mainly have two methods here: the indeterminate coefficients method and the parameter variation method. Of the methods I mentioned, the parameter variation method is the strongest; although not necessarily the simplest. I will use parameter variation, to solve this problem, to illustrate the method.

To use the parameter variation method the idea is to construct a matrix that I will call a **fundamental matrix** $\Phi(t)$  it is defined in the following way $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\Phi(t):=\begin{pmatrix} \uparrow & \uparrow \\ v_{1} & v_{2} \\  \downarrow & \downarrow \end{pmatrix}}}$$
where $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are the eigenvectors of matrix $A(t)$, then we find the inverse of the fundamental matrix that I will call $\color{blue}{\boxed{\Phi^{-1}(t)}}$ and as a final step, we use the well-known formula from variation parameter method to find the particular solution given by $$\color{blue}{\boxed{X_{p}(t)=\Phi(t)\int \Phi^{-1}(t)F(t)\operatorname{dt}}}$$

> Note that it is not necessary to add a constant of integration to the above identity for the same reason that you do not add the constant of integration in the parameter variation method for higher order ODE.

Returning to our problem, we can see that $$\Phi(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and $$\Phi^{-1}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} &  -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, you can find $$X_{p}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \int \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} &  -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 16e^{-t} \\-8t \end{pmatrix}\operatorname{dt}$$

I'll let you figure that part out.

Finally when you have solved that part you found $X_{p}(t)$ and so the general solution for your problem is given by $$\color{blue}{\boxed{X(t)=X_{c}(t)+X_{p}(t)}}$$

*I hope this detailed explanation will help you in your studies and future readers of MathSE.*

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rcl} 3x-y'-2y&=& 8t\\ x'-2x+y &=&16e^{-t} \end{array}\right.$$
Sum both DE:
$$x-y'+x'-y= 8t+16e^{-t}$$
$$(x-y)+x'-y'= 8t+16e^{-t}$$
$$u+u'= 8(t+2e^{-t})$$
Where $u=x-y$.